# Swift / iOS: How to assign value for OrderedDictionary variable?

Tags: ios, swift, variables

I want to assign value for `OrderedDictionary` (https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary) , by this way, it's ok.

```
var orderedDictionary: OrderedDictionary<String, Int> = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4]
```

But by this, it doesn't work.

```
// json data
let abc:[String:AnyObject] = ["A": [1], "B": [2], "C": [3], "D": [4]]
var od: OrderedDictionary<String, AnyObject> = abc
```

Or

```
var od: OrderedDictionary<String, AnyObject> = abc as! OrderedDictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Why? What's different there? And how to assign value for it?

Comment: OrderedDictionary is not a Swift dictionary. You can't arbitrary cast one to the other.

Comment: You are trying to cast standard Dictionary to unknown to Swift OrderedDictionary

Comment: So, in this case, i have to use `insertElement` to insert every single item to it? But by this way, i stll can't get ordered dictionary. How do i do it?

Comment: Yes. You may write custom init OrderedDictionary from Dictionary in extension. But if you wish __really__ ordered dictionary you should fill it by single item

Comment: @ShadowOf I've tried to insert single item but if i use for loop, i'll lose the ordering. So i can't do it by this way

Comment: Show us your loop please

Comment: `abc` is a Swift Dictionary, where the ordering is *unspecified*. You already lose the ordering when assigning `let abc = ...`.

Comment: I use: https://gist.github.com/Brandon-T/03e1c1122d9cf2702fb70ead4f6a8cc5 Just copy the same constructor and inherit: `DictionaryLiteralConvertible`

Comment: @Brandon I already did, i replaced the `init` method, but still can't assign the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are more different issues.

First of all, array is not AnyObject, so you have to change to

```
var orderedDictionary2: OrderedDictionary<String, Any> = ["A": [1], "B": [2], "C": [3], "D": [4]]
```

The second issue is when you are trying to assign dictionary directly, [DictionaryLiteralConvertible](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) is called (OrderedDictionary has extension to implement this protocol), but when you are trying to assign dictionary by some temporary variable, IMHO assign operator should be overloaded:

```
func = <T,U>(inout left: OrderedDictionary<T,U>, right: [T: U])
```

And the last issue is mentioned by Martin R. When regular dictionary is initialised, at this point information about order is lost.

**UPDATE**

Example initialization with temporary variable:

```
let array = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
let orderedArray: OrderedDictionary<String, Int> = OrderedDictionary(elements: array)
```

or

```
let array = [("A", [1]), ("B", [2]), ("C", [3])]
let orderedArray: OrderedDictionary<String, [Int]> = OrderedDictionary(elements: array)
```

**NOTICE**

JSON format:

An **object** is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

An **array** is an **ordered** sequence of zero or more values.

The terms "object" and "array" come from the conventions of JavaScript.

Comment: So, how else can i assign value for 1 variable if i don't name it? I have data in JSON format. I want to assign a part of it to this OrderedDictionary. I don't know what's `DictionaryLiteralConvertible` , i've read about it 3 times, but English is not my native language, and it's really hard to understand what is this :(

Comment: You can initialize OrderedDictionary by array of tuples for example: let array = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
let actual: OrderedDictionary<String, Int> = OrderedDictionary(elements: array). But be careful, JSON format doesn't guarantee order too. You will have to introduce order variable inside JSON format...

Comment: Yes, after a while, i realize that the trouble is JSON format doesn't guarantee order, so i think using `OrderedDictionary` is useless in this case. I have to put the order keys in an `Array` and use it as a sorting factor. I have to change API to return suitable JSON data for swift. This is so annoying.